# Excel VBA - FileToOpen Function IF a specific cell contains specific data in it

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

Appreciate your support as i trying to run a code to make file opens only IF opened file certain cell contains specific data in it

for example
i need opened file to open only when C2 contains "available" and hence, i could compelete remaining processing for this file but if opened file Cell C2 equals "maintain"
then i need to close the opened file and pop up a message you selected the wrong file

i tried the below code but the result was:
if the opened file Cell C2 contains maintain as a word
the remaining processing is not compelete unlike if the file opened cell c2 contains available
but the wrong sheet still open and pop up message is not shown

PArt of the Code related to this issue:
'File to Open
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Set Ssheet = OpenBook.Worksheets("Default")
     If (Ssheet.Cells(3, "C") = "Maintain") Then
     Ssheet.Close
     MsgBox "You have Chose check Maintain File ! please choose Available File"
     GoTo ErrHandler
End If
```

Comment: `Ssheet.Close` doesn't make sense. `Ssheet` is a worksheet, which does not have a `Close` method.

Comment: @BigBen Ssheet = OpenBook.Worksheets("Default")
Does not mean that it 9bject for the entire workbook of this sheet as normally without if command the sheet is closed with this command normally and processing is completed

Comment: `OpenBook.Close` would make sense. You *can* close a workbook. `Ssheet.Close` does not make any sense because you cannot close a worksheet.

Comment: You can do what BigBen mentioned, `OpenBook.Close`, or you can do `Ssheet.Parent.Close`. It's the same, but you may want to add `SaveChanges:=False`. Your `If` clause contains extra parentheses that are unnecessary and you forgot `End If` in the second `If` statement. Put the `End If` right after `Goto ErrHandler`. Also, `Goto` is usually avoided.

Comment: @BigBen Many thanks, yeah it worked it was due to my poor knowledge with VBA as I thought that I set ssheet as a objective workbook not worksheet ... Thanks again :)

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks too for your help and more clarification you provided .. and please note that it is only a part of the code so I did not forget the second End IF but I forgot to copy it from the original code as I tried minimize the code as I can for my issue  .. Once again thanks for your help :)